# Get all multiple selected dropdown using get method in php

Tags: php, ajax, get, multiple-select

Here is a my [html form](http://brandsneed.com/allselectevalue/) ,In this form have three select dropdown and i am submitting this form using ajax on onchange. So if i select first dropdown it will display first selected dropdown value. If I select second dropdown it will display only the second selected dropdown value. But i wanted to display all selected dropdown I mean first, second and third selected dropdown value.

So my question is how to get all selected value from multiple select tag. And here ajax file `file_ajax.php` code

```html
<?php 
if($_GET) 
{ 
  print_r($_GET); 
} ?>
```

And here is my script

```html
$("form select").on('change', function () { 
             $.ajax({
            url: 'file_ajax.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: $(this).serialize(),  
                  dataType: 'html'
                  })
               .done(function(data){
               $('#form-content').html(data);
             })
             .fail(function(){
                 alert('Form Submission Failed ...'); 
             });
             
         });
```

Please reply me thank you.

Comment: Please also add your javascript or jquery code, you're using for ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in this function

```
$("form select").on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'file_ajax.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'html'
    })
    .done(function(data){
        $('#form-content').html(data);
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert('Form Submission Failed ...');
    });
});
```

You serialize **only** one select dropdown

```
$(this).serialize()
```

`this` means the object from which the event occurred

Comment: Ok @Adrian Bobrowski, let me to check

Comment: Thank you @Adrian Bobrowski, I added this var dataString = $("#chkveg, #chkveg1, #chkveg2").serialize();